# Keep valid reference of the current Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to show some dialogs as debug in my app.
The structure of the app itself is written so that it is easier to actually call and show the dialog from a static class with static methods. These methods all points toward a bigger method which eventually take care of the requests.

What I'd like to achieve is to call an eventual Dialog (I'm using the Material Dialog library by afollestad on github) which needs a reference to the current activity.

I actually have a `private static Activity sActivity;` field in the class, and the relative `setActivity(Activity activity)` method.

Currently, I've got my own CustomApplication from which I call this:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            MyStaticClass.setActivity(activity);
        }
        [...]
}
```

which is not working as intended because this

```
try {
     Utils.showSimpleDialog(sActivity, "Error", message);
} catch (MaterialDialog.DialogException d) {
     d.printStackTrace();
}
```

is always calling the catch case.

My question is, is it possible to avoid the `setActivity` call from every single Activity? If yes, how? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to keep a static reference to an Activity as it can cause memory leaks with leaked contexts.

**Edit to answer if it would still be dangerous if setting static activity to null in onDestroy as previously asked in a comment under this answer**
Setting to null in onDestroy doesn't always serve as a workaround to this because if you run out of memory you can get into a state where Android can actually stop at the onPause stage of the lifecycle and not even hit onDestroy. Keeping static contexts is generally to be avoided.

---

It looks like showSimpleDialog already takes an Activity parameter. When you are calling it from an Activity, simply pass `this` , or from a fragment, pass `getActivity()`. If this call to showSimpleDialog is called from another utility method you've implemented, just pass an activity to that method also rather than setting a static Activity on the class.